# Wifi Adhoc:: Android mobile to android mobile

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I need to transfer messages from an Android phone to another android phone using Wifi without using an external access point. 
I tried to search in web, but my efforts were in vain. I have already rooted the phones and patched the WPA_supplicant file so that each phone can detect adhoc networks.
I have the following questions.

1. Is it possible to transfer messages from phone to phone using wifi?
2. Is there any tutorial or example available for  boradcasting 
   messages through wifi?
3. I found an interesting video in youtube 
   (link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zsydxw2BGEI).  Can anybody
   tell me how that guy made the Wifi adhoc work?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I am trying to do the same thing .

Comment: Well, one thing you can look is to use Android phones as access point by employing wifi-tethering

Comment: Is that for android 2.2 and without rooting android phone?

Comment: @user1030768: The tethering is simply making the android-phone an AP. But how to make the android-phone itself a node in an Ad-hoc network and allow other android phones in the same ad-hoc network to pass messages in control-less-ly manner .. I am trying to do the same, but now I am focusing in founding an android phone that support ad-hoc networking without having to have root-access ?

Answer (score 0):

You can google "connect adhoc to android" !! i found some videos
https://www.youtube.com/results?q=adhoc%20android&um=1&ie=UTF-8&gl=IN&sa=N&tab=w1